# How to extract image frames from mjpeg with EXIF data?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following command to obtain image frames from an mjpeg video.

ffmpeg -i record.mjpeg -f image2 frame%d.jpg

Then I use an EXIF tool to read the extracted image but I can't see EXIF metadata.

I'm not sure if I have to use other command such that the image frames I extracted contain exif. Thank you very much.

(I use ffmpeg-20150812-git-542562e-win64-static.)

Comment: Are you sure it actually *has* exif metadata?

Comment: @RolandSmith Thanks. I can't be sured whether I have exif. So, I just wonder if the command I use is correct. I can't check exif data from mjpeg file.

Comment: You could try a `ffprobe record.mjpeg -v quiet -show_frames` and see if there are any `TAG`s

Comment: Normally exif data is only found in JPEG files from digital cameras. Looking into a *movie* from my digital camera, there are no exif tags to be found.

Comment: @aergistal Thanks. I have tried that before and there is none.

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank you.